# No such file or directory: '/home/runner/work/FastAPI-CICD/FastAPI-CICD/venv/bin/python3'

Tags: python, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, python-venv

I am trying to setup a simple CI/CD pipeline. Th below is my `.yml` file for Github Action.

```
name: FastAPI CI/CD

on:
  # Trigger the workflow on push
  push:
    branches: 
      # Push events on main branch
      - main 

# The Job defines a series of steps that execute on the same runner.
jobs:

  CI:
    # Define the runner used in the workflow
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:   
      # Check out repo so our workflow can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      # Step-1 Setup Python
      - name: Set up Python
        # This action sets up a Python environment for use in actions
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'
          # optional:x64 x64 or x86. Defaults to x64 if not specified

      # Step-2 Install Python Virtual ENV
      - name: Install Python Virtual ENV
        run: pip3 install virtualenv && pip install --upgrade virtualenv

      # Step-3 Setup Virtual ENV
      # https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows
      - name:  Virtual ENV
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: cache-venv # name for referring later
        with:
          path: venv # what we cache: the Virtual ENV
          # The cache key depends on requirements.txt
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-venv-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements*.txt') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-venv-

      # Step-4 Build a Virtual ENV, but only if it doesn't already exist
      - name: Activate Virtual ENV
        run: python3 -m venv venv && source venv/bin/activate && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
        if: steps.cache-venv.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'

      - name: Run Tests   
        # Note that you have to activate the virtualenv in every step
        # because GitHub actions doesn't preserve the environment   
        run: . venv/bin/activate && pytest
      - name: Create archive of dependencies
        run: |
          cd ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
          zip -r9 ../../../../api.zip .
      - name: Add API files to Zip file
        run: cd ./api && zip -g ../api.zip -r .
      - name: Upload zip file artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: api
          path: api.zip
```

However I got this problem. I am sure that this file exists in my directory. What is the problem?
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jllYY.png)
[dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NsYv.png)

I tried to upgrade `virtualenv` after the installation step but still not working. I also tried to use `virtualenv -p python3 venv` but it is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  - name: Set up Python version
    uses: actions/setup-python@v3
    with:
      python-version: '3.10'

  - name: Create and start virtual environment
    run: |
      python -m venv venv
      source venv/bin/activate
```